# Issue when using AES 128 using JDK 7

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, aes

I have a stand alone Java program that gets triggered from Mainframe_JCL. 
The Java program has a code to encrypt and decrypt a string.

When I run the program in my Local. After encryption, when I decrypt, the value is correct ( I am getting the string that I have supplied for encryption).

But when this runs on Mainframe by JCL executing this.. I have getting weird decrypted value.. kind of Junk.

Not sure whats the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

We are using following JDK : 
IBM SDK for z/OS, Java Technology Edition, Version 7

Below are methods used for encryption and decryption :

```
    public static String encrypt(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte iv[] = new byte[16];
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        BASE64Encoder enc = new BASE64Encoder();
        try {            
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            random.nextBytes(iv);
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKeySpec(), ivspec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return URLEncoder.encode(enc.encode(iv)+enc.encode(encrypted), "UTF-8");
    }

    public static String decrypt(String text) {
        byte iv[] = new byte[16];
        String decrypted  = "";
        byte[] splitText = null;
        byte[] textToDecrypt = null;
        BASE64Decoder dec = new BASE64Decoder();
        try { 
            text = URLDecoder.decode(text, "UTF-8");
            text = text.replaceAll(" ", "+");
            splitText = dec.decodeBuffer(text);
            splitText.toString();
            for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
                iv[i]=splitText[i];
            }
            textToDecrypt = new byte[splitText.length - 16];
            for(int i=16;i<splitText.length;i++){
                textToDecrypt[i-16]=splitText[i];
            }
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKeySpec(), ivspec);
           decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(textToDecrypt));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

static SecretKeySpec spec = null;
public static SecretKeySpec getKeySpec() throws IOException,
                                            NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    if (spec == null) {
        String keyFile = "aes_key.key";
        spec = null;
        InputStream fis = null;
        fis = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keyFile);
        byte[] rawkey = new byte[16];
        fis.read(rawkey);
        fis.close();
        spec = new SecretKeySpec(rawkey, "AES");
}
return spec;
}
```

Comment: Do you do encryption and decryption on the same machine? How do you get your input? Reading a file? What encoding do you use?

Comment: Yes I am doing encryption and decryption on same machine. I get my input from a table column value. its a varchar set to Java String variable. Encoding used is BASE64Encoder.

Comment: can you provide an example that is not working?

Comment: I have added the methods I am using : Basically, I have a AES Key file Method getKeySpec() reads this key file and returns an object of SecretKeySpec . The methods encrypt() and decrypt() will use these method and will perform encryption, decryption for the given parameter strings. The code is working fine on my Local machine. But its not working on cross platform , eg.. the encrypted string when passed to different platfrom viz mainframe, OR salesforce etc.. the other platform is unable to decrypt to actual value. Here I got stuck

Answer (score 1):

You haven't supplied enough information to run your code (so I won't fix), but I see two things that may corrupt the result:

1. You should prefix the 16 byte IV before you encode using Base64; currently you are possibly mixing IV and ciphertext.
2. You should define the character encoding for `toBytes` and `new String`; currently you may have two different platform character sets to content with.

Finally, URL encoding base 64 may not be very efficient, you are better off just replacing the `+` and `/` characters [by URL safe counterparts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

---

So I was in for a puzzle:

```
package nl.owlstead.stackoverflow;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public final class VeryStaticStringEncryption {

    private static final String KEY_FILE = "aes_key.key";
    private static final SecretKey AES_KEY = retrieveSecretKey(KEY_FILE);

    private VeryStaticStringEncryption() {
        // avoid instantiation
    }

    public static String encrypt(final String text) {
        try {
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            final int n = cipher.getBlockSize();

            final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            final byte[] iv = new byte[n];
            random.nextBytes(iv);
            final IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AES_KEY, ivspec);

            final byte[] plaintext = text.getBytes(UTF_8);
            byte[] ciphertext = Arrays.copyOf(iv,
                    n + cipher.getOutputSize(plaintext.length));
            final int ciphertextSize = cipher.doFinal(
                    plaintext, 0, plaintext.length,
                    ciphertext, n);

            // output size may be bigger, but not likely
            if (n + ciphertextSize  < ciphertext.length) {
                ciphertext = Arrays.copyOf(ciphertext, n + ciphertextSize);
            }

            return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext);
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not encrypt string", e);
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(final String text) {
        try {
            // throws IllegalArgumentException if decoding fails
            final byte[] ciphertext = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(text);

            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            final int n = cipher.getBlockSize();

            // CBC specific
            if (ciphertext.length < n + n || ciphertext.length % n != 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ciphertext has incorrect size");
            }

            final IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(ciphertext, 0, n);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, AES_KEY, ivspec);
            final byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext, n, ciphertext.length - n);
            return new String(plaintext, UTF_8);
        } catch (final GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not encrypt string", e);
        }
    }

    public static SecretKey retrieveSecretKey(final String keyResource) {
        try (final InputStream fis = VeryStaticStringEncryption.class.getResourceAsStream(keyResource)) {
            final byte[] rawkey = new byte[16];
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                final int b = fis.read();
                if (b == -1) {
                    throw new IOException("Key is not 16 bytes");
                }
                rawkey[i] = (byte) b;
            }

            if (fis.read() != -1) {
                throw new IOException("Key is not 16 bytes");
            }

            return new SecretKeySpec(rawkey, "AES");
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            // e may contain confidential information
            throw new IllegalStateException("AES key resource not available");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ct = encrypt("owlstead");
        System.out.println(ct);
        String pt = decrypt(ct);
        System.out.println(pt);
    }
}
```

Note that I used a package-local resource as I didn't want to clutter up my SO project.

IMPORTANT NOTE: CBC encryption is not secure for transport mode encryption if a man-in-the-middle attack is possible. Refactor to GCM mode if required.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. the getKeySpec() was missing in the post.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. The method getKeySpec() was missing in the post. I have added it.  Basically, I have a AES Key file & method getKeySpec()  reads this key file and returns an object of SecretKeySpec . The methods encrypt() and decrypt() will use these method and will perform encryption, decryption for the given parameter strings. The code is working fine on my Local JDK machine. But its not working on cross platform , eg.. the encrypted string when passed to different platfrom viz mainframe, salesforce etc.. the other platform is unable to decrypt to actual value.

Comment: Try and specify `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` for encoding /decoding the plaintext. It's probably not an issue, but a single `read` of the key is not good stream handling - fewer than 16 bytes may be returned. Copying binary keys can be tricky as well if they are handled as text by the system (e.g. by FTP). Could you try the fixes I've indicated yourself?

Comment: It is exactly as @MaartenBodewes says -- the line `URLEncoder.encode(enc.encode(iv)+enc.encode(encrypted), "UTF-8");` should be something like `URLEncoder.encode(enc.encode(org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.addAll(iv,encrypted)), "UTF-8");`

Comment: And `.getBytes()` -> `.getBytes("UTF-8")` + `new String(...)` -> `new String(..., "UTF-8")`